# Button wont call a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

completely new to javascript as of an hour ago. Trying to get a button to call a function. It was working fine like 20 minutes ago, but all of a sudden it's being touchy and deciding now to work, what am I missing here?

```js
function sortFunction() {
  var totalNums = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter?", "");
  var numsArray = [];

  for (i = 0; i < totalNums; ++i) {
    var nums = prompt("Please enter number " + (i + 1), "");
    numsArray[i] = nums;
    document.write(numsArray[i] + " ");
  }

  if (nums == "x") break; // if user enters x, break loop

}
```

```html
<p> Click the button to enter and display an array of numbers!</p>
<button onclick="sortFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Your `break` is outside of a loop. Indenting blocks would help.

Comment: `"SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch"` in the browser developer console, the first place you should look when code doesn't work

Comment: Also, using `document.write` in your function will cause havoc

Comment: Thanks! The break was indeed the issue. What's the proper way in javascript to end from an if statement? For example user enters X, I now want to end instead of having the program continue.

Comment: You do not break from an if statement. break is used for coming out of loops.

You can write the entire piece of code in an if, like if the value == 'X'  don't do anything, else do whatever you are doing.

Comment: @Tman simply using `return` will end execution of the function. `break` is used within loops and `switch` statements in JavaScript.

Comment: The if statement needs to be inside the loop. Right after `var nums = prompt(…);`.

Comment: Got it, so run the whole chunk of code UNLESS if(nums != 'x') , Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As previously commented, the if statement needs to be just after var nums = prompt line. We also use return most often to exit out of functions.

More importantly, rather than limiting the incorrect option to 'x', why not adjust it to:

```
  for (i = 0; i < totalNums; ++i) {
    var nums = prompt("Please enter number " + (i + 1), "");
    if (typeof nums === "number") {
      numsArray[i] = nums;
      document.write(numsArray[i] + " ");
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is put "if" inside of the function

```js
function sortFunction() {
  var totalNums = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter?", "");
  var numsArray = [];

  for (i = 0; i < totalNums; ++i) {
    var nums = prompt("Please enter number " + (i + 1), "");
    numsArray[i] = nums;
    document.write(numsArray[i] + " ");
  if (nums == "x") break; // if user enters x, break loop
}

}
```

```html
<p> Click the button to enter and display an array of numbers!</p>
<button onclick="sortFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with if condition it was placed outside the for loop. 
So this might work for you putting condition inside and will break the loop on value x

```
function sortFunction() {
var totalNums = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter?", "");
var numsArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < totalNums; ++i) {
    var nums = prompt("Please enter number " + (i + 1), 
    if (nums == "x"){
        break;
        }
    else{
        numsArray[i] = nums;
        document.write(numsArray[i] + " ");
    }  
}
```

}